# FFmpeg - What does non monotonically increasing dts mean?

Tags: ffmpeg, dts, ffprobe, audio-video-sync

**Observations - Part - I**

I saw a suggestion elsewhere to run the following command to see if there's something wrong with my .mp4.

```
ffmpeg -v error  -i ~/Desktop/5_minute_sync_output_15mn.mp4 -f null - 2>error.log
```

When I run the above command, I see a whole bunch of the logs on the lines of what's shown below.

> Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to
>   muxer in stream 0: 15635 >= 15635

This, from searching and reading up quite a bit, I understand that the decoding timestamp isn't in sequential order.

**Observations - Part II**

But, inspecting the frames of the same mp4 using the following command and some post processing, I don't see `pkt_dts` within the frames_info json being out of order for either of the video or audio streams.

```
ffprobe -loglevel panic -of json -show_frames ~/Desktop/5_minute_sync_output_15mn.mp4
```

This makes me doubt my initial understanding in **Observations - Part - I**

Are these 2 things not related?
Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Monotonically increasing means strictly increasing. You can't have two packets with the same value or a value lower than the previous one. Does it apply to the `ffprobe` output?

Comment: Okay. The monotonic part makes sense.
When I ffprobe it as shown in the second command in my Part II Observations, all pkt_dts values are strictly increasing. Not sure why.

Comment: Hi guys, 
anyone out there who can help me understand these logs? 
I can't make sense of it.
I'm seeing it on a consistent basis with other files too.

Comment: Here I am trying to find if I should worry about this or not :(

Answer (score 5):

---

This message is not about the input file's validity, it is from the output format not accepting non monotonous dts. Many input formats support non monotonous dts (`grep -r AVFMT_TS_NONSTRICT FFmpeg`) so it is not necessarily a problem with the file.

The `null` format does not need any timestamps as indicated by the `AVFMT_NOTIMESTAMPS`:

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/ce8f77a903e1108bde774d5e0e59d8cd24f18c46/libavformat/nullenc.c#L36

However, the dts check still happens unless `AVFMT_TS_NONSTRICT` is set in the `nullenc.c` flags:

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/ce8f77a903e1108bde774d5e0e59d8cd24f18c46/libavformat/mux.c#L563

This seems to be an oversight, it does not make sense to check the validity of the timestamps passed to the null format. Other formats that do not actually encode the data, like the hash format, also have the `AVFMT_TS_NONSTRICT` flag.

Comment: Look like someone else was annoyed by the spammy logs back in 2015 and [submitted a patch](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-January/167811.html) to add the `AVFMT_TS_NONSTRICT` flag to `nullenc.c`. I guess it wasn't merged. Shame.

Comment: @ollie Right, currently the check for equality is wrong, so  I still get with `media-video/ffmpeg-6.0-r3:0/58.60.60::gentoo`:


`[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f37e418bcc0] All samples in data stream index:id [1:-2147483648] have zero duration, stream set to be discarded by default. Override using AVStream->discard or -discard for ffmpeg command.
[hevc @ 0x55ee39edb300] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 10657898 >= 10657898`